# Collect data while users are off network and sync

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I was given a scenario where some of our users need to do some things while they won't have access to a network (on a laptop).  I was thinking that I could install SQL Express on their machines and use service broker to queue up their transactions and when they are backonline the messages could be sent to the receiving server.

Is this a valid option? Would you suggest a different technique? I was just thinking that using SQL Express for one over access would be better and I could then possibly take advantage of the service broker functionality in SQL Server?

Any thoughts? Thanks as always...appreciate the input.

--S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've seen used before that worked well was to use either SQL Express or SQL Server CE, the latter does not require an install (can be just deployed with assemblies), and will run in process, so no service is required.

When the user did have access to the network, the application would synchronize the two databases using the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx).